# How to hit the breakpoint at catch block when working with TPL

Tags: parallel-processing, breakpoints, task-parallel-library

As I started understanding thru the TPL. I got stuck over in this code. I have 2 task. Task1 thows ArgumentOutOfRangeException and Task2 throws NullReferenceException.

Consider this below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

            // create the cancellation token source and the token
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

            // create a task that waits on the cancellation token
            Task task1 = new Task(() => {
                // wait forever or until the token is cancelled
                token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(-1);
                // throw an exception to acknowledge the cancellation
                throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
            }, token);

            // create a task that throws an exceptiono
            Task task2 = new Task(() => {
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            });

            // start the tasks
            task1.Start(); task2.Start();

            // cancel the token
            tokenSource.Cancel();

            // wait on the tasks and catch any exceptions
            try {
                Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
            } catch (AggregateException ex) {
                // iterate through the inner exceptions using 
                // the handle method
                ex.Handle((inner) => {
                    if (inner is OperationCanceledException) {
                        // ...handle task cancellation...
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        // this is an exception we don't know how
                        // to handle, so return false
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

            // wait for input before exiting
            Console.WriteLine("Main method complete. Press enter to finish.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I have put the try catch block for Task.WaitAll(task1, task2). It should ideally hit the breakpoint in ex.handler statement inside Catch block. As I understand that whatever may be the result it should hit the catch block.

Same case is happening if I have task1.Result/task2.Result.

My Question is: In debug mode why isn't the breakpoint being hit at the catch block when I am intentionally throwing it from task as I want to examine the statements under catch block. It just puts yellow mark at saying "NullReferenceException unhandled by the user code".

```
Task task2 = new Task(() => {
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            });
```

How do I hit the break point at catch block???

Thanks for replying :)

Comment: When i run this code, i do get the User-unhandled break (since it is unhandled by that thread), but when i continue it does then hit the breakpoint inside the catch and the caught AggregateException does contain both thrown exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

As [Arne Claassen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32577/arne-claassen) explained in their comment, the debugger pauses execution at the point the original exception is thrown because the thread does not handle the exception. If you continue exceution (**F5** or **play button**), the program should continue to the point where you are handling the exception in your continuation.